# Jquery passing a parameter between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey i would to pass a parameter from a function in jquery, but i cant get it to work. what am I doing wrong? I would like to pass "name" from the click function to the dialog block function to prevent repeating of code

**Update:** I have define name after the function. however i still cannot pass it like this <%=GetUserName(name)%>

**Update 2** jsFiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/bbKw8/

```
            <div id="dialog-block" >
                <p>
                    <b>Friends List:</b>
                    <% =GetFriends(0) %>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="Div1">
                <p>
                    <b>Friends List:</b>
                    <% =GetFriends(0) %>
                </p>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                // the jQuery document ready handler
                $(function () {
                    var name;
                    // create our dialog
                    $('#dialog-block').dialog({
                        title: '<%=GetUserName(name)%>',
                        autoOpen: false,
                        width: 400,
                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function () {
                                closeDialog($(this))
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    // the button to open the dialog
                    $('#user0chair,#apDiv1').click(function (event) {
                        if (this.id == 'user0chair') {
                            $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
                            name = 1;
                        }
                        else if (this.id == 'user1chair') {
                            $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
                        }
                    });

                });

                function closeDialog(elem) {
                    elem.dialog("close");
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand the intention of your code. Perhaps you could upload a copy to jsfiddle.net and we could try it to see what it does?

Comment: keep it as your good habit to define variables with the key word `var` .. and put then right after the window ready function

Comment: heres the jsdfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/bbKw8/

Comment: you are wrapping the variable as a text ! with the qouts around it , this means that this is some text not a variable you should chnage the line to title: '<%=GetUserName(' + name + ')%>', my answer has been updated also

Comment: stop mixing server code with javascript and a lot of confusion will disappear. They don't run in same environment or at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Because you failed to define `name` with the `var` keyword, it is already accessible by any other code on the page.

Other than this special case, variables have function scope, so define a `var name...` at the level higher than both functions that require access to it.

[Why you should use 'var'](http://scribu.net/blog/javascript-var-keyword-for-php-developers.html)

Comment: just a question .. arent variables declared in a function will only work in that scope only ?!!

Comment: If you aren't in V8's strict mode (in which you'd get an error for this) assigning a value to an undefined variable (without the var keyword) puts it into the global object.

Comment: And actually, your because your questions is more general, there are other cases when this rule is bent; e.g. closures (Accessing of variables from parent functions from a child function)

Comment: thank mate ! but once again just to confirm the info , if i didnt declare the variable with var then it wont be scoped to my function?! (normally)

Comment: Yes, but you should always use var. Implicitly defined global variables are considered bad practice. You should always be as explicit as possible about your intent, so other people, or even you, can read your code and understand it.

Comment: thanks for the info , yeah i know it is bad , but just a thing to keep in mind ...

Comment: ok I defined var name after the function, however i still get an error message when i try to do the following

                         `code` var name;
                        // create our dialog
                        $('#dialog-block').dialog({
                            title: '<%=GetUserName(name)%>', `code`

Comment: Update your question, rather than putting code in the comments. My brain isn't that good at parsing minified javascript.

Answer (score 0):

just right after

```
 $(function () {
```

put 
`var name ;`

explanation :

create the variable in the global scope , and then we you assign it from a function it will be accessible out side it ..

you are wrapping the variable as a text ! with the qouts around it , this means that this is some text not a variable you should chnage the line to title:

```
'<%=GetUserName(' + name + ')%>'
```

this line will mean treat any thing between the quotes as text and when you come to name just get it value and append it to the text and then complete the text ..

edit : wait a second here , you cant pass javascript variable to function on the server side , except though ajax , but not like this .. you should use post or get to send it to the server and then grap it from there and fire the function and catch back the result !